# Qt/QML/OpenGL: Z-ordering doesn't work with semi-transparent items with OpenGL under QML

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

Been following the examples found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) and have an issue where semi-transparent items are always drawn on top of opaque items no matter their order in QML or how the z property is set.

With no OpenGL Item, everything works as expected

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import TestScene 1.0

Item {
    width: 160
    height: 120

    /*
    TestScene {
        // draw checkered pattern in OpenGL
    }
    */

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1

        x: 32
        y: 32
        width: 32
        height: 32

        color: Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.5)
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2

        x: 32+16
        y: 32+16
        width: 32
        height: 32

        color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 1, 1)
    }
}
```

desired

[image]

When uncommenting the TestScene item

result

[image]

This happens even if rect2 is set before rect1 and regardless of the z property of either item.

The OpenGL code in C++ is pretty much as the Squircle example, and this is on Windows 10 and Qt 5.14.

Just curious why this happens and if it can be prevented or is it just a limitation of drawing OpenGL under QML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at QOpenGLFrameBuffer.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html

It allows fine grained control of your opengl based item's placement in the QML scenegraph versus the technique you are using, which I believe allows rendering custom opengl items before or after the rest of the QML scene graph items are rendered.

There is a sample project located at:
qt\Examples\$QTVERSION\quick\scenegraph\textureinsgnode

Comment: I tried looking into this and didn't find anything about using QOpenGLFramebufferObject with QQuickItem and my qt examples directory (Qt5.14.1\Examples\Qt-5.14.1\quick\scenegraph) has no "textureinsgnode" example.
However, I did find this [blog post](https://www.qt.io/blog/2015/05/11/integrating-custom-opengl-rendering-with-qt-quick-via-qquickframebufferobject) about QQuickFramebufferObject which seems to be the replacement for the "OpenGL under QML" example.

Thanks for pointing me in a different direction as I probably wouldn't have found that without this post.

Comment: Here is a link to the example project https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quick/scenegraph/textureinsgnode?h=5.13